# Using credit on the day of closing date

Tags: credit-card, credit-score, credit

Would it not affect my credit score if I use my credit card
on the day of my closing date or a day prior the closing date?

Answer (score 1):

*Using* your credit card has no impact to your score, at any time ever.

What impacts your score is

- having an open (but not due) balance of less then 30% of your credit limit *reported*; this is a very minor impact;
- having an open (but not due) balance over 30% of your credit limit *reported*; that is a bit more impact;
- carrying a balance into the following bill; this has a moderate effect
- having an *overdue* balance reported; that has a *serious* effect.

All those reportings are normally done monthly, at the day of closing and billing.

If you want to be ultra-sure, pay off your total amount a day or two points *before* the bill is cut (look it up online); otherwise, there will be a minor impact of some points, but it will bounce back next month. *Using* your credit card is normal and expected (if not even desired); they are not worried about you using your card, but about you paying the bills.

If you pay off early (before even being billed), they will report zero usage, and *long-term*, it is going to affect your credit score slightly negatively.

Comment: Wait - regarding point 1 - is that a *negative* or *positive* impact ??

Comment: All four are negative, but if you have 0, it's long-term worse. Best is to use between 1-30%, and pay off fully each month.